# Accessing media drive over VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have set up a VPN server using OpenVPN on my home Ubuntu 10 box as a means to access my home network drives and media drives whilst at work and on the move. I get a valid connection, can ping and connect to any node on the network successfully. I can access my network drives but not the media drive.

A bit of digging suggests that this is something to do with 'multicasting' across the VPN. I can't seem to find any information on this nor any settings in the OpenVPN config or options files.

If multicasting needs to be enabled somehow, how can I achieve this? If I am missing the issue here, can someone enlighten me on my failures?

Comment: Can you access other computers on the network when using VPN or just the VPN host?

Comment: @TheLQ, I can. I can access my network drive, I can access the VPN host's HTTP server, I can access my windows desktop window's share and I can ping any other node on the network successfully via the VPN connection. However, the media drive is not accessible.